# Setting up managesieve on Dovecot

Tags: dovecot, ubuntu-20.04, sieve

I'm trying to get my head around setting up managesieved so that my users can make use of it. So far I have done:

```
apt-get install dovecot-sieve dovecot-managesieved
```

After some debugging, I found out I need to create **/home/user/sieve/tmp** for each user (and set as `user:mail` ownership).

Then I have to symlink that back to

```
/home/user/..dovecot.sieve /home/user/sieve/managesieve.sieve
```

So far so good. Some instructions tell you to put this in your /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf file:

```
protocols = imap pop3 managesieve
```

Doing this, I see a warning:

```
Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:2: protocols=managesieve has been renamed to protocols=sieve
```

I have restarted dovecot, and setup a test filter for myself:

```
require ["fileinto"];
# rule:[test 2]
if allof (header :contains "from" "andy.xxxx@xxx.com")
{
    fileinto "bla";
}
```

My understanding is that this should then pass through the filter, and move the email directly into the "bla" folder I have created in my IMAP folders. Unfortunately this doesn't happen.

Can anyone suggest anything else to try? I'm coming up blank now

Comment: replace `managesieve` with `sieve`, as suggested by the warning?

Comment: Additionally, IIRC this is just the protocol that allows users to modifier their filter rules.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider thanks - done that but it doesn't seem to pass "through" the users sieve filters? Looking in /etc/dovcot/90-sieve.conf , it says: `# Do not forget to enable the Sieve plugin in 15-lda.conf and 20-lmtp.conf` ... but I don't have a file like that (only 20-managesieve.conf , 90-sieve.conf and 90-sieve-extprograms.conf)